# write a shell script to display count of users currently logged in and write the count in "count.txt". Display the count.txt file content

Tags: linux, shell

> Display count of users currently logged in and write the count in `count.txt`. Display the `count.txt` file content.

I used this but it's not giving the right answer.

```
ls -l | wc > count.txt
cat count.txt
```

Comment: What does `ls -l` have to do with the number of users logged in? That's the number of files in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Barmar `ls -l` is not a correct command to have the number of users logged in.

Try *w* command. So thi muse looks like this :

```
w -h| wc > count.txt
cat count.txt
```

The *-h* argument is to remove headers line.

Answer (score 0):

```
who | wc -l > count.txt;
cat count.txt
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

This will work -

who | wc> count.txt

cat count.txt

Comment: This adds nothing to existing answers